# Angular service data not updating

Tags: angular

I have two method: **getUserProfile** which returns the user profile and **updateProfile** which updates user data.
 UpdateProfile method works correctly because it displays valid updated data in the database. I'm having a problem with the getUserProfile method, because after calling the updateProfile method the updated data in the component is not displayed, but displays the data before the changes [Data not updated correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJmaa.png). Only when I log out of the application and log in again It will  display updated data. 
I think the problem is with localstorage and userToken value because it is cleared after logout. And only after re-logging the getUserProfile method is called again and works correctly.[Changed data in database after calling updateProfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP1qi.png)

**Component class:**

```
      export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
      userData: any;
      profileForm: FormGroup;
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }
      ngOnInit() {
      this.formInitBuilder();
        this.authenticationService.getUserProfile().subscribe( (data: any) => {
          this.userData = data;
          this.profileForm.setValue({
            username: data.UserName,
            email: data.Email,
            firstName: data.FirstName,
            lastName: data.LastName
          });
          console.log(data);
        });

      }
      formInitBuilder() {
        this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group ({
          username: [ '' ],
          email: [ '' ],
          firstName: [ '' ],
          lastName: [ '']
        });
      }
      onSubmit(registrationForm: FormGroup) {
        if (registrationForm.valid) {
        this.authenticationService.updateProfile(this.profileForm.value).
         subscribe(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          });
        }
      }
}
```

**Service class:**

```
      getUserProfile() {
    return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/api/GetUserClaims',
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userToken'))})});
  }
  updateProfile(userData) {
    const profile = {
      Username: userData.username,
      Email: userData.email,
      FirstName: userData.firstName,
      LastName: userData.lastName,
    };
    const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/ChangeProfile', profile, {headers: reqHeader});
  }
```

**Web Api:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/GetUserClaims")]
    public AccountModel GetUserClaims()
    {
        var identityClaims = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identityClaims.Claims;
        AccountModel model = new AccountModel()
        {
            UserName = identityClaims.FindFirst("Username").Value,
            Email = identityClaims.FindFirst("Email").Value,
            FirstName = identityClaims.FindFirst("FirstName").Value,
            LastName = identityClaims.FindFirst("LastName").Value,
            LoggedOn = identityClaims.FindFirst("LoggedOn").Value
        };
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Your question has too many moving parts and also there is no clear [mcve]. Please refactor it and isolate the problem you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but the call to your api is only made once, don't expect your data to be updated unless you call `getUserProfile` again. When you refresh, your `getUserProfile` is executed and get the data you updated using `updateProfile`.